# Recursively accumulate elements of collection

Tags: scala, recursion

I have a collection of elements with an integer range such as

```
case class Element(id: Int, from: Int, to: Int)
val elementColl: Traversable[Element]
```

and I want to accumulate them into

```
case class ElementAcc(ids: List[Int], from: Int, to: Int)
```

according to the following algorithm:

1. Take one `Element` from my `elementColl` and use it to create a new `ElementsAcc` which has the same from/to as the `Element` taken.
2. Iterate over remaining elements in `elementColl` to look for an `Element` that has an overlapping integer range with our `ElementAcc`.
3. If one is found, add it to `ElementAcc` and expand the integer range of `ElementAcc` to include the range of the new `Element`
4. If none is found, repeat the process above on the remaining elements of `elementColl` that have not yet been assigned to an `ElementAcc`

This should result in collection of `ElementAcc`'s. While just recursively adding elements to an accumulator seems easy enough, I don't know how to handle the shrinking size of `elementColl` so that I don't add the same `Element` to multiple `ElementAcc`'s

**Edit:** I think I was unclear regarding the extension of the range. So let my clarify this on an example:

My accumulator currently has a range from 1 to 5. An Element with a range from 6 to 8 does not overlap with the accumulator range and thus will not be included. An Element with a range of 4 to 7 does overlap, will be included and the resulting accumulator has a range from 1 to 7.

Comment: Sort you sequence first (by (from, to) tuple), then do a fold. The rules for the fold are a bit subtle due to several different cases for ranges of the neighbouring elements, but it is doable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll go like this:

1) Write a function that takes an `ElementAcc` and an `Element` and returns an `ElementAcc`.
The function would look like:

```
def extend(acc: ElementAcc, e: Element): ElementAcc = {
  if(acc.from <= e.from && e.from <= acc.to)
    ElementAcc(e.id :: acc.ids, acc.from, math.max(acc.to, e.to))
  else if (acc.from <= e.to && e.to <= acc.to)
    ElementAcc(e.id :: acc.ids, math.min(acc.from, e.from), acc.to)
  else acc
}
```

`foldLeft` is often the good solution when accumulating objects.
It needs an initial value for the accumulator and an function that takes an accumulator and an element and returns an accumulator. Then it accumulates all elements of the `traversable`.

EDIT:

2) To accumulate on different lists you would have to create another function to combine a  `List[ElementAcc]` and an `Element` :

```
def overlap(acc: ElementAcc, e: Element): Boolean = {
  (acc.from <= e.from && e.from <= acc.to) || (acc.from <= e.to && e.to <= acc.to)
} 

def dispatch(accList: List[ElementAcc], e: Element): List[ElementAcc] = accList match {
  case Nil => List(ElementAcc(List(e.id), e.from, e.to))
  case acc :: tail =>
    if (overlap(acc, e)) extend(acc, e) :: tail
    else acc :: dispatch(tail, e)
}
```

3) And it's used with a foldLeft:

```
val a = Element(0, 0, 5)
val b = Element(1, 3, 8)
val c = Element(2, 20, 30)
val sorted = List(a, b, c).foldLeft(List[ElementAcc]())(dispatch)

sorted: List[ElementAcc] = List(ElementAcc(List(1, 0),0,8), ElementAcc(List(2),20,30))
```

Comment: The range adjustment is slightly wrong, but that is not that big of a problem. I was struggling with creating multiple `ElementAcc`'s, since each `Element` is supposed to be added only once. Therefore after creating one `ElementAcc`, the remaining collection of `Element`s is shortened by one to n.

Comment: @MarcoK I modified a bit `extend` so you can provide a generic zero to the `foldLeft` call. It avoids you to look inside your `Element` traversable. Hope that answer your question.

Comment: Yes, but what if we have a 3rd element `val c = Element(3, 4, 6)`. This should not be added to the first `ElementAcc` but create a new one. The Result should be something like `List(ElementAcc(List(2, 1),0,3), ElementAcc(List(3),4,6))`

Comment: This is more complicated. This time you need a method that would insert an `Element` inside of a list of `ElementAcc`. And if the the `Element` find two suitable accs, you want to merge this two accs, is that it ? This the problem of finding the number of connected components.

Comment: Ideally there should never be the case where an `Element` can be assigned to 2 different `ElementAcc`. We iterate of the `Element` collection and add to an `ElementAcc` until no `Element` satisfies the condition anymore. Only then a new `ElementAcc` is created. As @Ashalynd pointed out this is probably easiest done by sorting the collection first.